# Python Kivy log shows "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aioconsole'" - how to fix?

Tags: python, kivy

```
07-22 12:22:40.274  2211  2246 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
07-22 12:22:40.278  2211  2246 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
07-22 12:22:40.279  2211  2246 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'OpenGL ES 3.2 build 1.9@4893595'>
07-22 12:22:40.280  2211  2246 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Imagination Technologies'>
07-22 12:22:40.281  2211  2246 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'PowerVR Rogue GE8100'>
07-22 12:22:40.282  2211  2246 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 2
07-22 12:22:40.284  2211  2246 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <4096>
07-22 12:22:40.285  2211  2246 I python  : [INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
07-22 12:22:40.370  2211  2246 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
07-22 12:22:40.374  2211  2246 I python  : [INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
07-22 12:22:40.759  2211  2246 I python  :  Traceback (most recent call last):
07-22 12:22:40.760  2211  2246 I python  :    File "/home/vg/kivy/src/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 29, in <module>
07-22 12:22:40.762  2211  2246 I python  :  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aioconsole'
07-22 12:22:40.762  2211  2246 I python  : Python for android ended.
07-22 12:22:40.993  2211  2234 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x0 in tid 2234 (RenderThread), pid 2211 (org.test.myapp)
```

I thought I should add 'aiconsole' to buildozer.spec
requirements = python3,kivy,asyncio,aioconsole
but that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

NoModule error means you have to add that package in your buildozer.spec file